# Is it possible to write a lambda function for this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with a column "released" in the format "May 11, 2001 (Canada)". I want to break it into 3 columns `released_date`, `released_year`,    `released_month`. I have done it as below but I was wondering if and how to write this as a lambda function.

```
released_date = []

released_country = []

released_year = []

for x in movies['released']:

    date = x.split("(")[0]

    country = x.split("(")[1].replace(')','')

    released_date.append(date)

    released_country.append(country)
    
movies['released_country'] = released_country

movies['released_date'] = released_date

movies['released_date'] = pd.to_datetime(movies['released_date'])

movies['released_year'] = movies['released_date'].dt.year

movies['released_month'] = movies['released_date'].dt.month
```

Comment: please paste some sample data, format as code and provide expected output

Comment: "if and how to write this as a lambda function." This doesn't really make sense. I assume what you are thinking of is the technique where you write a function that can process *one* entry, and then use some special Pandas trick to apply it to the whole column. You are thinking of `lambda` because it's common to use it for *short, simple* functions that can then be in-lined in the call to the special Pandas thing. You should use the special Pandas thing. You should write a normal function for it, not a `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df['date'] = df['a'].str.split('(').str[0].str.strip()
df['released_country'] = df['a'].str.split('(').str[1].str.replace(')','')
df['date_p'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d, %Y')
df['released_date'] = df['date_p'].dt.date
df['released_month'] = df['date_p'].dt.month
df['released_year'] = df['date_p'].dt.year
```

Assuming original column in `a`

Comment: This way is surely more efficient, but it loses the conceptual grouping into a single "parse the release-date information" operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a helper function like below and call them with lambda may be:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "May 11, 2001 (Canada)"
>>> def my_func(data):
...     data = re.sub("[(),]", "", data).split(' ')
...     return data[0], data[1], data[2]
...
>>>
>>>
>>> my_func(data)
('May', '11', '2001')
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your head of the idea that `lambda` is any kind of special tool in itself, or that `lambda` is what's doing the work when you see others' code doing cool things with third-party libraries like Pandas.

**All** `lambda` is, is a convenient way to write *short, simple* functions, without having to give it a name, and put it inline with other code.

In exchange for that, you are very limited: instead of writing a normal function body, you write a *single expression* (the result of which is returned). That isn't practical in your case.

The neat thing that Pandas does, generally, is repeat code that works on a single cell, across an entire row, column or the entire DataFrame. Being able to do that sort of thing is *why you use Pandas*.

The Pandas tool that we want here is the [`apply` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) of the `movies['released']` Series (i.e., column of the DataFrame). That lets us use a function that handles a single entry from that Series, and apply it to the entire thing.

First, we write a normal function that processes a single release-date entry, and gives us a Series of the values we want:

```
def parse_release_date(x):
    date = pd.to_datetime(x.split("(")[0])
    country = x.split("(")[1].replace(')','')
    return pd.Series((country, date), ('released_country', 'released_date'))
```

(it is *possible* to write that as a `lambda`, but it makes things look a lot messier than they need to. Giving the function a name, here, also makes the code easier to understand.)

As explained in the documentation I linked, now we can `apply` that to our Series, and we get a DataFrame: each call to the function makes a row of values.

```
release_dates = movies['released'].apply(parse_release_date)
```

From there, we can simply insert columns back into `movies` in the normal way:

```
movies['released_country'] = release_dates['released_country']
movies['released_date'] = release_dates['released_date']
movies['released_year'] = release_dates['released_date'].dt.year
movies['released_month'] = release_dates['released_date'].dt.month
```

---

Alternately, you can use purely the fundamental operations provided by Pandas and as shown in @Vivek Kalyanarangan's answer - the same kind of thing that you do with `.dt.year` and `.dt.month`, but to solve the entire problem. `.str` works like `.dt` (but you get strings instead of Datetime objects), and it offers `replace`, `split` and `strip` methods that work like the corresponding string method (just applying it to every string in a Series). This is still a Series, so `[0]` gives you one of the entries, instead of giving you the first character of each string - for that, you need `.str[0]` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

released -> released_date, released_year, released_month, (released_country)

```
import re
pattern=r"\s*([a-z|A-Z]+)\s*([0-9]{1,2})\s*,\s*([0-9]{4})\s*\((\s*[a-z|A-Z]+\s*)\)\s*"
released_month, released_date, released_year, released_country = re.search(pattern, released).groups()
```

I think I know why you want Lambda but again I couldn't find the need of it.

Lambda is used frequently in following situations.

1. When a function, method takes a function as an argument but you can't be bothered to defined that function just for using it as argument.
   Example would be

   a.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
2. When a function is used just once and you can't be bothered to define it. Example would be

   new_list = list(map(lambda x: x**2, old_list))

So anyway my code code will parse "May 11, 2001 (Canada)" format into 4 strings.

1. May
2. 11
3. 2001
4. Canada

and then assign each to released_date/year/month/country variables.

You can further apply pandas functions to make those strings represent some datetime concept

To see how regex works, go to https://regexr.com/

and copy paste my "pattern" there